# Open Source Linux Web Hosting Panel with asp.net core support

Tags: linux, asp.net, web-hosting-control-panel

I'm looking for a good hosting panel for linux server that supports asp.net core websites. i have few php and asp.net core websites and i want to host them into my vps.

for example Ajenti is good option but its not supporting asp.net core websites. any alternative or advice?

the main problem with all hosting panels is:

i don't want to run and config every asp.net core applications manually.

is there a better way to run asp.net core apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after few days research i found a solution so i'll share it for other people having same problem:

first, there is no open source control panel that supports asp.net core directly yet but you can use ajenti-v to easily config your asp.net core websites in few simple steps ...

1- install manually dotnet core runtime and ajenti with nginx plugin on your server

2- login to ajenti panel and create website

3- in the website **manage** panel go to the **Content** tab

4- select **Reverse proxy** from dropdown and paste below configuration to the 
**Custom configuration** textbox :

```
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

5- select **Use only custom configuration and don't include standard parameters option**

*we almost done. now every call in your domain/ip:port will redirect to dotnet core application with nginx reverse proxy but we need to run our application in background using our control panel.

6- go to the **Processes** tab and Add new process with following example configuration:

```
Name : MyDotnetApp
Command : dotnet MyDotNetEntryPoint.Dll
Working directory: /srv/MyWebsiteFolderName
username : root (or any linux user with r/w access)
Enviroment : ASPNETCORE_ENVIROMENT=Production
```

click apply..... Done. 
your site is ready to use.

[more information about ajenti control panel](http://ajenti.org/)

[more information about config asp.net core and nginx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[more information about supervisord option in ajenti](http://supervisord.org/)